# When is Lexical Scope for a function within a function determined?

Tags: r, lexical-scope

I've looked at the other lexical scoping questions in R and I can't find the answer. Consider this code:

```
f <- function(x) {
  g <- function(y) {
    y + z
  }
  z <- 4
  x + g(x)
}
f(3)
```

`f(3)` will return an answer of 10. My question is why? At the point `g()` is defined in the code, `z` has not been assigned any value. At what point is the closure for `g()` created? Does it "look ahead" to the rest of the function body? Is it created when the `g(x)` is evaluated? If so, why?

Comment: It might help people to explain if you said what value you expected other than 10.

Comment: Note that in a fresh session, `f <- function(x){y}` will define `f` without issue. R doesn't care what's inside of `f` until it's called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `f` is run, the first thing that happens is that a function `g` is created in `f`'s local environment. Next, the variable `z` is created by assignment.

Finally, `x` is added to the result of `g(x)` and returned. At the point that `g(x)` is called, `x = 3` and `g` exists in `f`'s local environment. When the free variable `z` is encountered while executing `g(x)`, R looks in the next environment up, the calling environment, which is `f`'s local environment. It finds `z` there and proceeds, returning 7. It then adds this to `x` which is 3.

(Since this answer is attracting more attention, I should add that my language was a bit loose when talking about what `x` "equals" at various points that probably do not accurately reflect R's delayed evaluation of arguments. `x` *will be* equal to 3 once the value is needed.)